# “Subsection 2.4” vs. “section 2.4”

Tags: word-choice

When referring to the fourth subsection of the second section, which of the following should I write:

> As stated in subsection 2.4, ...
> As stated in section 2.4, ...

Are there standard rules for this?

In LaTeX, the `hyperref` package suggests to use the former, but a reviewer of a paper now suggested to use the latter.
Does it depend on the variant of the language (AE/BE)?

Comment: Different publications and style guides will assign different names to the various levels of division, and may even specify cross-reference style. Are you writing to a specific style guide? Listen to your editor. I believe that you can tell LaTeX to use different terms for automated cross-references, but you'd have to ask on TeX SE. (In normal English usage, it really wouldn't matter, but journals get more finicky about this kind of thing.)

Comment: There are no standard rules about that; it is up to you and/or the editors to decide what terminology will be used within that particular publication. However, **if** you have already decided that 1, 2, 3, etc. are to be called sections, then you cannot use the same word for 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, etc.; you have to refer to them in some other way (*subsection* would be the obvious choice).